# Getting Point cloud data from Openni driver

Tags: kinect, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Previously, I posted how to get started on the point cloud data for the Openni. Many of you posted that i need to get through the tutorials for ROS to have a better understanding. I have done that now.One posted this code(for the subscriber) for me... which was very helpful.I have some qns on this code:

1. We need to have both a publisher and subscriber node for the Kinect in order to get point cloud data.Am i right to say that?
2. how do u get the depth data from the point cloud data?

Really need of help. I am sorry if i ask stupid questions.

```
    #include <ros/ros.h>
    #include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
    #include <sensor_msgs/PointCloud2.h>

using namespace ros;
using namespace sensor_msgs;

class processPoint {
    NodeHandle nh;
    Subscriber sub;

public:
    processPoint() {
        sub = nh.subscribe<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("/camera/rgb/points", 1, &processPoint::processCloud, this);
    }

    ~processPoint() {   
     }

    void processCloud( const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud );
};

void processPoint::processCloud( const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& cloud ) {

}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    init(argc, argv, "processPoint");

    processPoint processPoint;

    Rate spin_rate(1);

    while( ok() ) {
        spinOnce();

        spin_rate.sleep();
    }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10259/getting-point-cloud-data-from-openni-driver/) by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2011-06-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-15**:
hi ppl ... is the page that give the correct code for point cloud : http://www.ros.org/wiki/pcl_ros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you working with ROS node system or do you want to read in the pointcloud from a single c/cpp file?

- In the first case you should roslaunch the openni_camera openni_node.launch file. This will publish the pointclouds on the /camera/rgb/points or /camera/depth/points topics (depending if you want XYZ or XYZRGB pointcloud). Look at roslaunch and the openni camera package.
- In the second case you should look at the PCL library (pointclouds.org) as they  have a ROS agnostic implementation.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-06-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-21**:
I actually have written a code in C++ for the depth data and the point cloud data.I would like to publish the data, how should i do that?

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-17**:
publishing and subscribing to the same topic u mean?

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-06-17**:
this requires subscribing to the topic of the openni camera and publishing to a new topic

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-16**:
basically what i am trying to do is that i have written a code for the point cloud in C++ and want to implement it using ROS and plot it out in RVIZ... Any suggestions how i can go about doing it?

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-16**:
thanks.... will read thru it... if i have qns, i will ask you....

**Comment by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) on 2011-06-16**:
Have a look here: http://www.pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/openni_grabber.php#openni-grabber

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-16**:
i need to include both the publisher and subscriber code right?

**Comment by [lakshmen](https://answers.ros.org/users/584/lakshmen/) on 2011-06-16**:
i just want to have point cloud information.which method is better?